# function with if/else statement on a form

Tags: forms, function, if-statement, getelementbyid

I am new to JavaScript, so this is one of my learning projects, but after a lot of research, I am stuck. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong? I can't seem to get a result to show up in the second text box after the first question is submitted. The two id's are in my html.

```
function myFunction(age1, level1) {

  var age1 = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var level1 = document.getElementById("level").value;

if (age1 <= 20) {
  level1.value = 1;
}
else if(age1 <= 40) {
  level1.value = 2;
}
else {
  level1.value = 3;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your variables both as a function parameter as well as inside the function itself. Also, you're pointing to "value" both in variable declaration as well as when you point to the variable.

This will cause problems.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you should delete your variable declarations from function(x,y) and point to "value" only once:

```
function myFunction() {

  var element1 = document.getElementById("age"); // removed value here
  var element2 = document.getElementById("level"); // removed value here

   if (element2.value <= 20) {
     element1.value = 1;
   }
   else if(element2.value <= 40) {
     element1.value = 2;
   }
   else {
     element1.value = 3;
   }
}
```

In this case, your variables are really "constants". You want to point to the same html element each time. In that case you just declare a variable, like you're already doing, anywhere you need them (so long they are in [scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/))

One reason why you would put them inside the function parameters is when you want to make your function act "dynamically" and reusable. Like so

```
function myFunction(elementIdToCheck, elementIdToSelect) {

  var elementToCheck = document.getElementById(elementIdToCheck);
  var elementToSet = document.getElementById(elementIdToSelect);

   if (elementToCheck.value <= 20) {
     elementToSet.value = 1;
   }
   else if(elementToCheck.value <= 40) {
     elementToSet.value = 2;
   }
   else {
     elementToSet.value = 3;
   }
}

myFunction("age", "level");
```